# Php accents / special character search and replace with regular expressions

Tags: php, symfony, search, preg-match-all

I want to look for a search term inside a given text and return an array of matches with the search term highlighted with html.

For example:

```
countMatch($needle, $haystack) { ... }
```

Given the needle = "foo", and the haystack "foo bar foo foo";

The code should return this array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "<strong>foo</strong>"
  1 => "<strong>foo</strong>"
  2 => "<strong>foo</strong>"
]
```

My code works fine, but I have the huge dilema with accents and other UTF8 characers:

1. If the search term contains an utf8 character like: (àáâãäçèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü), the function should **MATCH ALL** *fóo*, *fóo*, *fõo*, *etc*... **WITH** *foo*.
2. Same case for the haystack: **MATCH** *foo* **WITH ANY** *fóo*, *fóo*, *fõo*, *etc* inside haystack.
3. Also, the return array should show the highlighted matches and take previous 100 characers and subsecuent 100 characters before and after search term.

So far:

```
/**
 * Count existance of needle and return formated html string of needle
 * 
 * @param string $needle (search term)
 * @param string $haystack (text to search)
 * @return string|int
 */
private function countMatch($needle, $haystack) {
    $matches = array();
    $response = array();
    $i = 0;
    preg_match_all("#(.{0,100}$needle.{0,100})#iu", $haystack, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[0])) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $i+=1;
            $response[$i] = "..." . str_ireplace($needle, "<span class='marker'>".$needle."</span>", $match) . "..."; 
        }
        return $response;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This works fine it even is case insensitive. However, if I input "foó" I get no matches or if I input "foo" and the haystack contains "fóo, I get no matches.

**Expected Results:**

Example 1:

- needle = "foo"
- haystack = "this is a fóo right? this also contains thousands of other characters before and after the föo search term."
- Expected result:

  array:2 [
    0 => "**fóo**"
    1 => "**föo**"
  ]

Example 2:

- needle = "Foó
- haystack = "this is a foo right? this also contains thousands of other characters before and after the föo search term."
- Expected result:

  array:2 [
    0 => "....**foo**...."
    1 => "....**föo**...."
  ]

**NOTE:**

This regular expression: `#(.{0,100}$needle.{0,100})#iu` allows me to paste the leading and following 100 characters of the match.

Yes, as you already guessed, this is a little search engine using MariaDB / MySQL FULLTEXT INDEX and database has no problem with those characters, case sensitivity, etc. However, I can't paint the search results because the mentioned problem.

Original source code of controller:
[PlantaController](https://github.com/autocondat/blanes/blob/7411970d677d2c3d211cf15666edc819ba076751/src/Erparom/Autocondat/AdminBundle/Controller/PlantaController.php)

(Inside controller, relevant functions are getPlantaAction, buildResult, **countMatch**, explodeSearch)

View (to understand how I consume Ajax to paint results):
[Search form](https://github.com/autocondat/blanes/blob/7411970d677d2c3d211cf15666edc819ba076751/src/Erparom/Autocondat/AdminBundle/Resources/views/default/hierbasDashboard.html.twig)

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags. `mysql` removed

Comment: Please look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_levenshtein.asp

Comment: What are the length of your haystacks?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Haystacks are stored in a TEXT field inside the database, they usually contain full web pages and I need to print result also as webpages (the portions where the search term is matched)

Comment: @JesusSegnini Sorry perhaps my question was not clear. My problem is regarding regex and accented vowels.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it was not an irrelevant tag due to the context. Perhaps another solution (like "dude, just use Elastica") from the database layer may be my answer. Please undo your tag removal.